How to get partition scheme for filestream data?
Short version: is there a way to get the partition scheme for the FILESTREAM data used by a clustered index created on a partitioned table?
Longer version:
Say you want to partition a table storing FILESTREAM data, then the documentation says:
CREATE INDEX (Transact-SQL)

If the table is partitioned, the FILESTREAM_ON clause must be included
and must specify a partition scheme of FILESTREAM filegroups that uses
the same partition function and partition columns as the partition
scheme for the table. Otherwise, an error is raised.

So you create filegroups for rows and filestream data, a partition function and two partition schemes (again one for the rows and filestream data, respectively), like this:
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [FSPartitionTest]
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'FSPartitionTest', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\FSPartitionTest.mdf'), 
 FILEGROUP [DataPartitionA] 
( NAME = N'Data_A', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Data_A.ndf'), 
 FILEGROUP [DataPartitionB] 
( NAME = N'Data_B', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Data_B.ndf'), 
 FILEGROUP [FSPartitionA] CONTAINS FILESTREAM  DEFAULT
( NAME = N'FS_A', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\FS_A'), 
 FILEGROUP [FSPartitionB] CONTAINS FILESTREAM 
( NAME = N'FS_B', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\FS_B')
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'FSPartitionTest_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\FSPartitionTest_log.ldf')
GO

USE [FSPartitionTest]
GO

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [APartitionFunction] (INT)  
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (1);
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [DataPartitionScheme]
AS PARTITION [APartitionFunction]
TO ([DataPartitionA], [DataPartitionB]);
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [FSPartitionScheme]
AS PARTITION [APartitionFunction]
TO ([FSPartitionA], [FSPartitionB]);
GO

CREATE TABLE [FilestreamTable] (
    [Partition] INT NOT NULL
    , [Id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [UX_FilestreamTable_Id] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ON [PRIMARY]
    , [FilestreamData] VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL
    , INDEX [UX_FilestreamTable_Partition_Id] UNIQUE CLUSTERED  (
                [Partition],
                [Id]
            ) ON [DataPartitionScheme]([Partition]) FILESTREAM_ON [FSPartitionScheme]
)  ON [DataPartitionScheme]([Partition]) FILESTREAM_ON [FSPartitionScheme]
GO

Then you can query the partition schemes and the indexes like this:
SELECT *
FROM sys.partition_schemes

SELECT T.[name], I.[name], I.[data_space_id]
FROM sys.tables AS T
JOIN sys.indexes AS I
    ON T.[object_id] = I.[object_id] 

Both partition schemes show up, they both use the same partition function and the clustered index references the DataPartitionScheme in sys.indexes. However, the partition scheme used for the FILESTREAM data is not referenced. In this case, there is only one other partition scheme using the same partition function and having filestream filegroups as targets. For any practical scenario, we would be done. No one would add another partition scheme, right?
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [FSPartitionSchemeB]
AS PARTITION [APartitionFunction]
TO ([FSPartitionB], [FSPartitionA]);
GO

CREATE TABLE [FilestreamTableB] (
    [Partition] INT NOT NULL
    , [Id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [UX_FilestreamTableB_Id] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ON [PRIMARY]
    , [FilestreamData] VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL
    , INDEX [UX_FilestreamTableB_Partition_Id] UNIQUE CLUSTERED  (
                [Partition],
                [Id]
            ) ON [DataPartitionScheme]([Partition]) FILESTREAM_ON [FSPartitionSchemeB]
)  ON [DataPartitionScheme]([Partition]) FILESTREAM_ON [FSPartitionSchemeB]
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [FSPartitionSchemeC]
AS PARTITION [APartitionFunction]
ALL TO ([FSPartitionA]);
GO

CREATE TABLE [FilestreamTableC] (
    [Partition] INT NOT NULL
    , [Id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [UX_FilestreamTableC_Id] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ON [PRIMARY]
    , [FilestreamData] VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NULL
    , INDEX [UX_FilestreamTableC_Partition_Id] UNIQUE CLUSTERED  (
                [Partition],
                [Id]
            ) ON [DataPartitionScheme]([Partition]) FILESTREAM_ON [FSPartitionSchemeC]
)  ON [DataPartitionScheme]([Partition]) FILESTREAM_ON [FSPartitionSchemeC]
GO

How can we determine, which table uses which partition scheme? Are there any views, that directly reference the data_space_id used by an index for FILESTREAM data?
Workaround:
There is one thing i noticed, but I am not completely sure if it works 100% of the time. The sys.partitions view has a filestream_filegroup_id column:
SELECT T.[name]
    , I.[name]
    , I.[data_space_id]
    , P.[partition_number]
    , FG.[name]
FROM sys.tables AS T
JOIN sys.indexes AS I
    ON T.[object_id] = I.[object_id]
JOIN sys.partitions AS P
    ON I.[object_id] = P.[object_id]
        AND I.[index_id] = P.[index_id]
JOIN sys.filegroups AS FG
    ON P.[filestream_filegroup_id] = FG.[data_space_id]

The view destination_data_spaces also has a column destination_id, which - I suppose - matches the partition_number:
SELECT PS.[name]
    , DDS.[destination_id]
    , FG.[name]
FROM sys.partition_schemes AS PS
JOIN sys.destination_data_spaces AS DDS
    ON PS.[data_space_id] = DDS.[partition_scheme_id]
JOIN sys.filegroups AS FG
    ON DDS.[data_space_id] = FG.[data_space_id]

So I guess one could check if the filegroups referenced by destination_data_spaces match the ones referenced by partitions for every partition:
WITH A AS (
    SELECT T.[name] AS [Table]
        , I.[name] AS [Index]
        , PS.[name] AS [PartitionScheme] -- for row data
        , FSPS.[name] AS [FS_PartitionScheme] -- candidate
        , FG.[name] AS [FS_DestinationFilegroup] -- referenced by partition scheme
        , PFG.[name] AS [FS_PartitionFilegroup] -- referenced by partition
        , CASE WHEN FG.[name] = PFG.[name] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [FilegorupsMatch]
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY T.[object_id], I.[index_id], FSPS.[data_space_id]) AS [NumPartitions]
        , SUM(CASE WHEN FG.[name] = PFG.[name] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  OVER (PARTITION BY T.[object_id], I.[index_id], FSPS.[data_space_id]) AS [SumMatches]
    FROM sys.tables AS T
    JOIN sys.indexes AS I
        ON T.[object_id] = I.[object_id]
    --partition scheme used for row data
    JOIN sys.partition_schemes AS PS
        ON I.[data_space_id] = PS.[data_space_id]
    --look for candidate partition schemes, that are used for FILESTREAM data
    --must use the same partition function
    JOIN sys.partition_schemes AS FSPS
        ON PS.[function_id] = FSPS.[function_id]
            AND PS.[data_space_id] <> FSPS.[data_space_id]
    --destination must be a FILESTREAM filegroup
    JOIN sys.destination_data_spaces AS DDS
        ON FSPS.[data_space_id] = DDS.[partition_scheme_id]
    JOIN sys.filegroups AS FG
        ON DDS.[data_space_id] = FG.[data_space_id]
            AND FG.[type_desc] = 'FILESTREAM_DATA_FILEGROUP'
    --get the partition where partition_number matches desination_id
    JOIN sys.partitions AS P
        ON I.[object_id] = P.[object_id]
            AND I.[index_id] = P.[index_id]
            AND P.[partition_number] = DDS.[destination_id]
    --find the filegroup referenced by the partition
    LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups AS PFG
        ON P.[filestream_filegroup_id] = PFG.[data_space_id]
)
SELECT [Table], [Index], [PartitionScheme], [FS_PartitionScheme]
FROM A
WHERE [NumPartitions] = [SumMatches]
GROUP BY [Table], [Index], [PartitionScheme], [FS_PartitionScheme]

There sould be one row per Index, unless some clown does this:
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [FSPartitionSchemeB2]
AS PARTITION [APartitionFunction]
TO ([FSPartitionB], [FSPartitionA]);
GO

So, if someone can confirm that indeed the partition_number always matches the destination_id, we can at least identify the partition scheme up to a unique definition (excluding NEXT USED), but still no definite data_space_id.

Found a way outside of SSMS using PowerShell. I used dbatools, but it will probably also work with the SqlServer module.
$Tables = Get-DbaDbTable -SqlInstance localhost -Database FSPartitionTest
$Tables.Indexes | Format-Table Parent, Name, PartitionScheme, FileStreamPartitionScheme

Would still be iteresting to know, if there is a management view providing this info.
